# Disable Or Enable Checkbox Array Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have Following codes:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="sakit">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="izin">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="sakit">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="izin">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can i disable checkbox in first tr element without make changes in second tr, otherwise i can disable checkbox in second tr element without make changes in first tr?

Comment: You want to do this in your HTML? or is this dynamic markup and needs to be controlled in JS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To explain you, why your question was downvoted: This is so easy to solve problem, solved millions of times so far, that asking questions like that, show _absolutely no effort of trying to solve this problem yourself_. This is a Q&A site, where we prefer asking: "I have this problem, I tried this, this and that and I failed.". Questions like: "I have this problem, please solve it for me" are very likely to get downvoted. BTW: Marking your question text, right clicking and selecting `Search Google...` gave me **three** links with solution! It took me **5** seconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to target elements using a css selector.

For targeting the first `<tr>`

`document.querySelector('tr:first-child input').disabled = true;`

or for targeting the second `<tr>`

`document.querySelector('tr:last-child input').disabled = true;`

Comment: +1 for reminding us, that we can do _really much_ in pure Javascript, without need to summon jQuery/Zepto!

Comment: Thank you, but how if i have four tr elements? can i disable checkbox in third of tr element?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable a checkbox with: `CheckboxObject.disabled = true;`

Comment: Is that really your markup? I ask because you have dupe values.

Comment: @AdrianLynch What do you mean? O_O

Comment: The values in row 1 are the same as those in row 2. Just get the feeling it's not the real markup.

Comment: @AdrianLynch Ah you meant that question for the OP =D

Comment: Oh and I'll ask before anyone else does... can you use jQuery? :D

Comment: @AdrianLynch To cite a text from my T-shirt (it's Chinese!): "_Objective reality is just a delirium, caused by a lack of caffeine in your blood system._". Hitting wrong comment button forces me to ask, if you don't have coffee-level critical at this moment (like I do?) :]

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you all you have to do is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ck[]" value="sakit" disabled>
```

in JS you would do this:

```
 var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].type == "checkbox")
        fields[i].disabled = true;
    }
```

this would disable the first checkbox on page.. if you need something different, let me know.